# Iterate through php variable div class using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble using variable generated php div classes and jQuery to use the fadeToggle() feature.
I've got two elements in question.  The first contains a link to click and the second contains a description about the link and I want to add a simple fadeToggle to the first div when clicked to show and hide the description.  However, the div classes are dynamically generated using a php for loop.  I've got 12 different links and 12 different descriptions that get inserted from outside folders using a php for loop.  Here's the code:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?> 
<p>
<a href="" onclick="return false" class="<?php echo "project$i-text-link-visible"; ?>">
    <span class="text-expand-symbol"></span>
     View project details:
</a>
</p>

<!-- PROJECT DESCRIPTION -->
<div class="<?php echo "project$i-description-hidden"; ?>">        
    <?php include 'descriptions/project' . $i . '.inc.html.php'; ?>
</div>  
<?php endfor; ?>
```

So i'm having trouble using jQuery's fadeToggle because I do not know how to iterate through the dynamically generated php div classes.  If I change the div class to something static like "project-description", the script I tried causes every description box to open at once when I click on any of the links.  Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

You can check out the site and see the problem for yourself, if you like.
Visit http://www.romanleykin.com/projects and scroll down to the "Class Projects" section to get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Currently, the site uses an ugly javascript code that changes the css properties from hidden to visible, but I would like to use jQuery for this.  Any ideas would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) sample of) the rendered HTML. JavaScript doesn't work on PHP server-side scripts, only on what the browser sees client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [custom data attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?> 

<a href="#" data-target="<?php echo $i ?>"> ... </a>

<div id="target_<?php echo $i ?>"> ... </div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Then the JS code:

```
$(function(){

    $('a[data-target]').on('click', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $('#target_' + $(this).attr('data-target')).fadeToggle();

    });

});
```

This way you tie each anchor to its related div without messing with classes.

Comment: Thank you very much, moonwave.  That was perfect.  It did it exactly.  Could you direct me anywhere so I can learn a bit more about tying anchors to divs.  This is the first I've heard of how to do that.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I can't come with a proper resource right now - just mind that custom data attributes do not mess with html validness, so you can't use [but not abuse!] how many you want. Just ask on SO again whenever you need!

Comment: I was also wondering how to attach them to the <span class=text-expand-symbol"></span> so that each time I click on it, the image (which is a background-image prop. in css) will change to a minus (another background-image jpeg)

Comment: I just figured it out.
HTML:
    <span class="text-expand-symbol" id="symbol_<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>

and i added this line to your jQuery function:

        $('#symbol_' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggleClass('text-hide-symbol');
    });

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to add an extra class to the php generated  tag, ie you a will have two classes:

```
class="something-common <?php echo $phpgenerated; ?>"
```

So basically you code will look like:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?> 
<p>
<a href="" onclick="return false" class="project-link <?php echo "project$i-text-link-visible"; ?>">
    <span class="text-expand-symbol"></span>
     View project details:
</a>
</p>

<!-- PROJECT DESCRIPTION -->
<div class="project-description <?php echo "project$i-description-hidden"; ?>">        
    <?php include 'descriptions/project' . $i . '.inc.html.php'; ?>
</div>  
<?php endfor; ?>
```

And you can use the selector as:

```
$('a.project-link')
OR
$('.project-link', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run a similar loop with jQuery you should be able to assign the event handlers to the links in the same way you created them in PHP:

```
<script> 
for (i=1; i<=12; i++) 
{ $('.project' + i + '-text-link-visible').click(function()
  { 
    // use the fadeToggle() on the description <div> here
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using dynamically generating classes or id in your tags.

See the link below, this should help

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/ivokof/5/edit)